# Property undefined - Can't get call fetched JSON object 2 times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, undefined, react-props

I am trying to pass fetched & parsed JSON data I stored in a variable from my file App.js to a component via props (but the same bug also occurs if I only want to console.log the data) in Chrome.
But I can not pass or console.log the data more than one time without getting the error message: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'title')".

This is my code in App.js:

```
import './App.css';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import SpentTimeItem from './components/SpentTimeItem';

function App() {
  const [jsonData, setJsonData] = useState([{}]);
  const fetchData = () => {
    fetch('data.json', {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Accept: 'application/json',
      },
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setJsonData(data);
      });
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []); // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

  console.log('App.js jsonData[0].title', jsonData[0].title);
  console.log('App.js jsonData[1].title', jsonData[1].title);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header"></header>
{/*This is the buggy part. Calling it once with jsonData[0] works, but as soon as I do it a second time with jsonData[1], nothing works anymore.*/}
      {jsonData && <SpentTimeItem passedJsonData={jsonData[0]} />}
      {jsonData && <SpentTimeItem passedJsonData={jsonData[1]} />}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The error (main) error message in Chrome is: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'title')".
I don't know why it's not working, my only guess is, that it has to do something with the re-rendering of the page and that the data is somehow gone once I call the stored parsed JSON data a second time.

Comment: I'm sorry. It's jsonData - jsonData2 is something I tried out and cut out for this post, it was a cloned object of jsonData. You can read it just like jsonData. 
I have edited the post.

Comment: It's because `jsonData[0]` doesn't exist at the time of the render. If you want to log the change you need to use `useEffect` with `jsonData` as a dependency: `useEffect(() => console.log(jsonData), [jsonData]);`. And `jsonData` _does_ exist (it has a length of one empty object) which is why your JSX is failing too. Maybe `useState([])`, and then check for `jsonData.length` instead.

Comment: So when I want to pass the data as props to the component (instead of just logging it out), I have to make use of the useEffect inside the return of the app function or where would I have to make use the useEffect?
And where should I use the useState([]) with the check for jsonData.length?

Comment: Well, that's a completely different question. At the moment your component is `fetching` the data, not having the data passed into it. So that issue is something the parent component needs to resolve.

Comment: App.js is fetching data, the parent component so to say. But what do you mean with it does not have the data passed into it? App.js is getting the data, so it can't be passed the data, instead, it should get the data and work with it without any problems like "property is undefined"